# Xdebug with VSCode for Laravel, Sail, WSL2

Tags: php, xdebug, vscode-debugger, wsl-2, laravel-sail

I'm currently developing a backend application with Laravel Sail. Developing on Windows with VSCode and WSL2 (VSCode with remote WSL mode).

The backend only provide an API for a frontend app. I use Postman to test my backend and would like to set up Xdebug so that I can step debug in VSCode.

It seems the breakpoints are never catched. Although I already did set
`SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug` in my .env file and added a configuration in VSCode launch.json

```json
{
    "name": "Listen for Sail Xdebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9003,
    "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
},
```

Can anyone help me finding out what is the issue? I already check different similar post though none seems to solve my issue. I always see:

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port)
```

I use php:8.2, sail:1.21.2, Laravel 9.52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out the solution to my issue. Here the problem was launch.json was missing "hostname" key parameter (see https://docs.devsense.com/en/vscode/debug/launch-json apparentrly hostname is required especially on linux system)

Correct launch.json should like like:

```
{
    "name": "Listen for Sail Xdebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9003,
    "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    "hostname": "localhost"
},
```

So to resume. To set up Xdebug in this environment:

- Add `SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug` to your `.env` file
- Create a configuration `launch.json` as above
- Make sure debuging is triggered:

  - With Postman set cookie XDEBUG_SESSION=whatever
  - With browser use debug extension
  - Alternatively set environment variable XDEBUG_SESSION=1 in `docker-compose.yml` so that debug is triggered for every execution

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        ...
        environment:
            ...
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            XDEBUG_SESSION: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        ...
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

Comment: Maybe you can add details on what you did setup?